# PhpStorm 2016.2.2 xdebug configured in php and in PhpStorm but breakpoints don't stop

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

I configured Xdebug in php.ini and I see it in `phpinfo()`.
And I see the Xdebug version in Interpreter I have XAMPP v3.2.2 in Windows 10.
I attach some pictures to explain what I have.

Please help me how can I make PhpStorm stop at breakpoints?

My php.ini

---

[XDebug]

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Interpreters

[image: Interpreters]

Languages & Frameworks>PHP>Debug

[image: Languages & Frameworks>PHP>Debug]

Comment: Do not use xdebug 2.5 RC on Windows -- it does not work right now. **Use xdebug stable 2.4.1** for now - as simple as this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40803303/783119

Comment: Thank you a lot it's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `xdebug.remote_host="localhost:8081"` to `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`. You already specified the port in `xdebug.remote_port`, so the host setting must contain only host name.

Also check that port 9000 is really held by PHPStorm. There can be a conflict with PHP FPM, because it uses the same port by default.