# waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug) gets stuck

Tags: php, windows, apache, netbeans, xdebug

I am using windows 8, Netbeans 8.2, php 5.6, Apache and mysql. I installed them manually and did not use all-in-one package like WAMP.

When I click on debugging icon (Ctrl+F5) it gets stuck on "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" while shows the page completely without stopping at the break points.

I reviewed all the possible solutions but none of them worked for me. Such as:

1. Changing the remote_host from "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 or even to the ip address of my machine
2. Changing the port from 9000 to different ports. Also checking the "Session-ID = netbeans-xdebug"
3. Setting the default "web browser" on Netbeans
4. Checking https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and following the instruction
5. Setting the date.zone in php.ini
6. Checking the firewall (as far as I could find my firewall does not block the connection)
7. Restarting httpd.exe (Apache) and netbeans and browser

Here are some info which gained from my system:

From https://xdebug.org/wizard.php:

> Tailored Installation Instructions
>
> Summary
>
> Xdebug installed: 2.5.0rc1 
> Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
> Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x64
> Zend Server: no
> PHP Version: 5.6.27
> Zend API nr: 220131226
> PHP API nr: 20131226
> ?Debug Build: no
> Thread Safe Build: yes
> Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
> Configuration File: C:\php\php.ini
> Extensions directory: ext
> You're already running the latest Xdebug version

From php -m command:

> [PHP modules]
> bcmath
> calendar
> .
> .
> . (I deleted them intentionally)
> [Zend modules]
> Xdebug

From netstat | findstr 9000

> TCP   127.0.0.1:9000          mycomputername:62936        CLOSE_WAIT 
> TCP    127.0.0.1:62936      mycomputername:9000         FIN_WAIT_2 
> TCP    [::1]:9000           mycomputername:62935        CLOSE_WAIT 
> TCP    [::1}:62935          mycomputername::9000        FIN_WAIT_2

Last but not least in php.ini there was no [Xdebug] section!! there was some lines but as a separated section like some people said there was nothing so at the end of file I added these lines:

> [xdebug] 
> zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
> xdebug.remote_enable = 1
> xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
> xdebug.remote_enable = on
> xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
> xdebug.remote_port = 9000

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Did you try [these](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue) steps?

Comment: @Shashanth yes I checked it as well. I think the problem or one of the problems is FIN_WAIT_2. As [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi) explains the server for some reason closes the request but not completely!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use xdebug 2.5 RC on Windows -- it has issues (does not work -- regardless what IDE is used, be it NetBeans or PhpStorm).

Use stable **xdebug 2.4.1** for now.

- https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1361
- https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1366

Comment: I tried XDebug 2.3.1 instead of XDebug 2.5 and the problem remains exactly the same. This was not the solution for me. I still experience the problem on Eclipse and NetBeans.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya The issue I was referring was specific to Windows only and applicable to xdebug 2.5 RC1 **ONLY** -- they were fixed in xdebug itself. So yeah -- your case might be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

[xdebug]

xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

istead of

[xdebug]

xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of different things as well. Not sure if any of the suggestions I found on the web helped. My final change that actually got it working was to switch the project url from http to https (project - properties - run configuration - project url).